# How to sort stringlist with comments

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I have stringlist with comments (like Ini file section content):

```
;comment c
c=str1
;comment b
b=str2
;comment a
a=str3
```

Any ideas how to sort this list by names to:

```
;comment a
a=str3
;comment b
b=str2
;comment c
c=str1
```

Comment for pair should be linked with pair during sorting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to parse the `TStringList` content into a second list that separates and groups the name, value, and comment strings together, then sort that list on the names as needed, then repopulate the `TStringList` with the sorted groups.  For example:

```
uses
  ...
  System.Classes,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Generics.Defaults,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.StrUtils,
  System.Types;

type
  ItemInfo = record
    LeadingText,
    Name,
    Value: string;
  end;

  ItemInfoComparer = class(TComparer<ItemInfo>)
  public
    function Compare(const Left, Right: ItemInfo): Integer; override;
  end;

function ItemInfoComparer.Compare(const Left, Right: ItemInfo): Integer;
begin
  if (Left.Name <> '') and (Right.Name <> '') then
    Result := AnsiCompareStr(Left.Name, Right.Name)
  else if (Left.Name <> '') then
    Result := -1
  else
    Result := 1;
end;

procedure SortMyList(List: TStringList);
var
  Compare: IComparer<ItemInfo>;
  Items: TList<ItemInfo>;
  Info: ItemInfo;
  I: Integer;
  InText: Boolean;
  S: String;
begin
  Compare := ItemInfoComparer.Create;
  Items := TList<ItemInfo>.Create(Compare);
  try
    Items.Capacity := List.Count;
    InText := False;

    for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
    begin
      S := Trim(List[i]);
      if (S = '') or (S[1] = ';') then
      begin
        if InText then
          Info.LeadingText := Info.LeadingText + #13 + List[i]
        else
        begin
          Info.LeadingText := List[i];
          InText := True;
        end;
      end else
      begin
        Info.Name := List.Names[I];
        Info.Value := List.ValueFromIndex[I];
        Items.Add(Info);
        Info := Default(ItemInfo);
        InText := False;
      end;
    end;

    if InText then
      Items.Add(Info);

    Items.Sort;

    List.Clear;
    for I := 0 to Items.Count-1 do
    begin
      Info := Items[I];

      if Info.LeadingText <> '' then
      begin
        for S in SplitString(Info.LeadingText, #13) do
          List.Add(S);
      end;

      if Info.Name <> '' then
        List.Add(Info.Name + '=' + Info.Value);
    end;
  finally
    Items.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple procedure that will sort and also deal with spaces as cargo. I also added code to handle comments at the end of the file.

This will work with older versions of Delphi that do not have generics or advanced types as in Remy's answer (provided as convenience for those using older versions)

```
function SortKeys(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  result := CompareText(List.Names[Index1], List.Names[Index2]);
end;


Procedure SortStringListWithComments(AStrings: TStrings);
var
 LCargoText: TStringList;
 LSortedText : TStringList;
 s: string;
 i : integer;
begin
  LCargoText := nil; 
  LSortedText := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to AStrings.count-1 do
    begin
      s := Trim(AStrings[i]);
      if (s='') or (s[1] = ';') then //LCargoText and blank lines attached to sorted strings (Boolean short circuit assumed here) 
       begin
        if LCargoText = nil then
          LCargoText := TStringList.Create;
        LCargoText.Add(AStrings[i]);
      end
      else
      begin
        LSortedText.AddObject(AStrings[i], LCargoText);
        LCargoText := nil; //set nil to deal with cases where we have no   comments for a following key value pair
      end;

    end;

    LSortedText.CustomSort(SortKeys);

    // LSortedText.sort -  will cause a1=x to be sorted before a=x

    AStrings.clear;

    for i := 0 to LSortedText.count-1 do
    begin
      if  LSortedText.objects[i] <> nil then
      begin
        AStrings.AddStrings(TStringList(LSortedText.Objects[i]));
        LSortedText.Objects[i].Free;
      end;
      AStrings.Add(LSortedText[i]);
    end;

    if LCargoText <> nil then
    begin
      AStrings.AddStrings(LCargoText) ; //comments orphaned at the end of the file
      LCargoText.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LSortedText.Free;
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: I used generics since I knew they were available, as the question is tagged XE8. In any case, the only changes I would suggest is adding exception handling to ensure things get cleaned up properly in case of an error, and change `Sort()` to `CustomSort()` so you can sort by just the actual names only (like the OP asked for) and not by entire lines. Your sort handler can use `TStringList.Names[]` to extract the names of each line.

Comment: Provided as a convenience for others. I agree custom sort will be needed since numbers have lower ordinal value than =. There are no known exceptions that I need to handle, but I will do a finally for free

Comment: Regarding exceptions, I was thinking more along the lines of memory allocation errors at the least, not so much other runtime errors.  You should always use `try/finally` at a minimum when dealing with local `Create/Free` pairs. And don't forget that `TStringList` does not own its `Objects[]` pointers, so you have to `Free` them manually before freeing the `TStringList` itself if you do use a `finally` to free it.